# Cannot start Android emulator in Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I'm trying to run the [PhoneWord](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/) tutorial Android app, with Xamarin in VS2015. I've got everything coded up in c# and it builds fine. However, when I go to run it on an emulator, nothing happens. I've created AVDs from the existing Nexus5 and Nexus6 definitions, as well as added a definition for a Galaxy S7, all using API level 21 (5.0 Lollipop). My app targets API level 21 (5.0 Lollipop), has it as a minimum requirement, and is compiled with 5.0 (Lollipop).

When I start debugging, the emulator screen pops up with its controls, but nothing happens. Sometimes I'll get "Android" text to show up across the center of the screen, but other times it'll just be a black screen. I've copied the output from some log files below, but am completely new to Android development so don't know what other log / debug information is available, or if this is a problem with my installation, my app, my emulator settings, my hardware, or something else.

I've tried starting the emulator before debugging in VS or debugging first and letting it start the emulator. I've let it sit for an hour or more, with no change.

I've seen references to VT-x and Intel HAXM, but haven't changed anything there. My emulators are all ARM (armeabi /armeabi-v7a).

output from [logcat](http://pastebin.com/index/utdMRBsg)

Xamarin IDE log:

```
    Xamarin.VisualStudio.UnhandledExceptionsManager Error: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:31:41.9755] An unhandled error occurred. Details: Error type 2
android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:298)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249)


Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: Error type 2
android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:298)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249)

   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.c__DisplayClass77_0.b__0(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Devices.DeviceManager Error: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:34:22.9377] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Project unavailable.
   at EnvDTE.Project.get_FullName()
   at Clide.Solution.Adapters.MsBuildAdapter.Adapt(ProjectNode from)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IAdapter , Object )
   at Clide.Patterns.Adapter.AdapterService.Adapt[TSource,TTarget](TSource source)
   at Clide.Patterns.Adapter.AdapterService.Adaptable`1.As[T]()
   at Clide.Sdk.Solution.ProjectNode.As[T]()
   at Clide.Solution.Implementation.UserProjectProperties..ctor(ProjectNode project)
   at Clide.Sdk.Solution.ProjectNode.get_UserProperties()
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Devices.DeviceManager.GetBestDeviceFor(IProjectNode projectNode, IEnumerable`1 availableDevices) in C:\data\lanes\3513\00fa5cc4\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Devices\DeviceManager.cs:line 128
```

Xamarin monodroid log:

```
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:06.3451] [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:06.3521] [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r11c\).
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:06.3601] [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:06.3751] [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:06.3942] [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory not found.
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:06.4042] [I:sdk]:                  Looking for Java 6 SDK..
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:06.4112] [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion found.
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:06.4192] [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6\JavaHome not found.
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:06.4322] [I:sdk]:                    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7\JavaHome found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55).
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:06.4662] [I:Unknown]:              Found Xamarin.Android 7.0.2
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:06.4772] [I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 21, 22, 23
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:14.6236] [I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:14.6446] [D:]:                     Tracking avd started
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:14.6626] [D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\Mark\.android\avd'
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:14.6746] [D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:14.6846] [I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:14.6956] [D:]:                     avd watcher android path: 'C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\android.BAT'
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:35:16.8547] [D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 2 devices
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:36:08.1347] [D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: emulator-5554   offline
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:36:08.1457] [I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:36:27.8368] [D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: emulator-5554   device
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:36:27.8458] [I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:36:27.8598] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:36:27.8748] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:36:49.6961] [I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 21, 22, 23
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:36:49.7461] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:36:50.7321] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS" -e "packages" "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime,Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_21,HelloAndroid2.HelloAndroid2" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:36:58.2065] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 cat /data/system/packages.xml
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:18.2327] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 pm install "/data/local/tmp/HelloAndroid2.HelloAndroid2-Signed.apk"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:23.6120] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 rm "/data/local/tmp/HelloAndroid2.HelloAndroid2-Signed.apk"
MonoDroidLog Error: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:24.1470] [E:]:                     Deployment failed
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?

   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.c__DisplayClass91_0.b__0(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:24.8721] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 date +%s
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:25.2461] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 setprop "debug.mono.extra" "debug=127.0.0.1:8947:8948,timeout=1486676275,loglevel=0,server=y"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:25.5571] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:25.8891] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE}"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:26.0201] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET}"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:26.1601] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.ExternalStorageDirectory"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:31.4024] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 "echo" "-n" "${EXTERNAL_STORAGE}"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:31.5895] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "HelloAndroid2.HelloAndroid2/md5c35c20f10c18d97cfa5803a7c4a6812a.MainActivity"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:41.6850] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 ps
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:42.2211] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am force-stop HelloAndroid2.HelloAndroid2
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:37:42.2461] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 setprop "debug.mono.connect" ""
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:38:43.8396] [D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:38:43.8556] [I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:39:05.9028] [D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: emulator-5554   offline
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:39:05.9149] [I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:39:24.8799] [D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: emulator-5554   device
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:39:24.8919] [I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:39:24.9049] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:39:24.9209] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:39:44.6171] [I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 21, 22, 23
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:39:44.6371] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:39:45.2531] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS" -e "packages" "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime,Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_21,HelloAndroid2.HelloAndroid2" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:39:53.1496] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 cat /data/system/packages.xml
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:10.3725] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 pm install "/data/local/tmp/HelloAndroid2.HelloAndroid2-Signed.apk"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:15.9999] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 rm "/data/local/tmp/HelloAndroid2.HelloAndroid2-Signed.apk"
MonoDroidLog Error: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:16.4479] [E:]:                     Deployment failed
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?

   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.c__DisplayClass91_0.b__0(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:16.7279] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 date +%s
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:17.1079] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 setprop "debug.mono.extra" "debug=127.0.0.1:8949:8950,timeout=1486676447,loglevel=0,server=y"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:17.4169] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:17.8090] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE}"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:18.0240] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET}"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:18.1630] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.ExternalStorageDirectory"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:23.6083] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 "echo" "-n" "${EXTERNAL_STORAGE}"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:23.8193] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "HelloAndroid2.HelloAndroid2/md5c35c20f10c18d97cfa5803a7c4a6812a.MainActivity"
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:33.7989] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 ps
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:34.3339] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am force-stop HelloAndroid2.HelloAndroid2
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:40:34.3509] [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 setprop "debug.mono.connect" ""
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:42:05.8061] [D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
MonoDroidLog Information: 0 : [2017-02-09 15:42:05.8201] [I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working, although I'm not sure if it was only 1 of the steps I did or a combination of them.

I had two layouts (Main.axml and ListLayout.axml) in the project, probably from another tutorial, but only 1 of them was filled out. My `MainActivity` was calling the empty layout. I changed it to call the correct layout.

My project settings also didn't have any supported architectures (Project->Properties->Android Options->Advanced), so I checked on `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`. I also checked on the option (On the Packaging tab) to generate one package per architecture, and unchecked the options to use the shared runtime and fast deployment.

Doing all this, I was able to get the emulator to run and test the `Phoneword` app.

I then enabled virtualization in my BIOS, checked on the `x86` architecture, defined a new emulator device with the Intel x86 CPU, and am able to run the emulator much quicker now.