# Using emulator-5554 setprop "debug.mono.extra" "" fails

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a Xamarin Forms app with Visual Studio 2022 and every time I get to emulator-5554 setprop "debug.mono.extra" in the Xamarin Diagnostics log, it fails with "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."
This is because there is nothing in the second quote after "debug.mono.extra". From looking at others copying messages from this command line, I'm missing the IP and some other information that should go in those quotes. Here's how my string looks:

> Using emulator-5554 setprop "debug.mono.extra" **"    "**

The full string should look something like this:

> "setprop "debug.mono.extra"
> **"debug=127.0.0.1:8947:8948,timeout=1486676275,loglevel=0,server=y"**

I bolded out the part that is not showing in my log.
Why is that missing in this property?  Is there any place I can add it or manually provide it?

I'm able to connect to the device as can be seen below, so I don't believe the connection is the issue.

[image]

Somehow some variable is missing during initialization of the application.

Since this is an RSS application, I am trying to connect to the Internet.  The WiFi on my emulator shows that I have a poor connection to the Internet.

Is is it something in my Network parameters?  Is there a firewall blocking?

Here's the Xamarin Diagnostics while doing "getprop":

```
-- Start GetProperties - 07/06/2022 16:20:08 (575.4627ms) --
[INPUT] getprop
[OUTPUT]
[build.version.extensions.r]: [0]
[cache_key.bluetooth.get_bond_state]: [4650017401060636414]
[cache_key.bluetooth.get_profile_connection_state]: [4650017401060636417]
[cache_key.bluetooth.get_state]: [4650017401060636418]
[cache_key.bluetooth.is_offloaded_filtering_supported]: [4650017401060636413]
[cache_key.display_info]: [-5091728493901789156]
[cache_key.has_system_feature]: [-5091728493901789162]
[cache_key.is_compat_change_enabled]: [-5091728493901789066]
[cache_key.is_interactive]: [-5091728493901789171]
[cache_key.is_power_save_mode]: [-5091728493901789150]
[cache_key.is_user_unlocked]: [-5091728493901789138]
[cache_key.location_enabled]: [-5091728493901789136]
[cache_key.package_info]: [-5091728493901789065]
[cache_key.telephony.get_active_data_sub_id]: [5107482523010396561]
[cache_key.telephony.get_default_data_sub_id]: [5107482523010396530]
[cache_key.telephony.get_default_sms_sub_id]: [5107482523010396536]
[cache_key.telephony.get_default_sub_id]: [5107482523010396534]
[cache_key.telephony.get_slot_index]: [5107482523010396535]
[dalvik.vm.appimageformat]: [lz4]
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xms]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xmx]: [512m]
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-max-image-block-size]: [524288]
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-minidebuginfo]: [true]
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-resolve-startup-strings]: [true]
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-updatable-bcp-packages-file]: [/system/etc/updatable-bcp-packages.txt]
[dalvik.vm.dexopt.secondary]: [true]
[dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit]: [192m]
[dalvik.vm.heapmaxfree]: [8m]
[dalvik.vm.heapminfree]: [512k]
[dalvik.vm.heapsize]: [512m]
[dalvik.vm.heapstartsize]: [8m]
[dalvik.vm.heaptargetutilization]: [0.75]
[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xms]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xmx]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.isa.x86.features]: [default]
[dalvik.vm.isa.x86.variant]: [x86_64]
[dalvik.vm.isa.x86_64.features]: [default]
[dalvik.vm.isa.x86_64.variant]: [x86_64]
[dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold]: [500]
[dalvik.vm.minidebuginfo]: [true]
[dalvik.vm.usejit]: [true]
[dalvik.vm.usejitprofiles]: [true]
[debug.atrace.tags.enableflags]: [0]
[debug.force_rtl]: [false]
[debug.hwui.renderer]: [skiagl]
[debug.mono.extra]: []
```

As you can see in the last line, the parameter debug.mono.extra is coming in blank.

Here's where and how it fails:

```
-- End GetProcessId --
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 setprop "debug.mono.extra" ""
[E:]:                     Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidLogger.LogError(String task, String format, Object[] args) in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidLogger.cs:line 63
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass118_0.<RunShellCommandAsync>b__0() in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 1012
[E:]:                     Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidLogger.LogError(String task, String format, Object[] args) in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidLogger.cs:line 63
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass118_0.<RunShellCommandAsync>b__0() in D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 1012
-- Start SetProperty - 07/06/2022 16:21:01 (63.8245ms) --
[INPUT] setprop "debug.mono.extra" ""
[OUTPUT]

-- End SetProperty --
```

Here's the output from the Debug log:

```
am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.companyname.rssreadermobile/crc64502c6059300e9765.MainActivity"
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.companyname.rssreadermobile/crc64502c6059300e9765.MainActivity }
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/RSSReaderMobile.Android.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/APES.UI.XF.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/FormsViewGroup.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/RSSReaderMobile.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation.Experimental.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.AsyncLayoutInflater.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Concurrent.Futures.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.ConstraintLayout.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.ConstraintLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CursorAdapter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.DocumentFile.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.DynamicAnimation.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Interpolator.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.UI.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.Utils.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModelSavedState.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.LocalBroadcastManager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Media.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.MultiDex.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.UI.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Palette.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Print.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.SlidingPaneLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Tracing.Tracing.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Transition.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable.Animated.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.VersionedParcelable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager2.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Essentials.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Java.Interop.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives(System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Int32)' to /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:124 [0x00000].
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/Mono.Security.dll [External]
[rssreadermobil] Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
[rssreadermobil] Unquickening 12 vdex files!
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[MultiDex] VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
[MultiDex] Installing application
[MultiDex] VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
[MultiDexLoader] /data/user/0/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/dexes
[MultiDexLoader] No dexes!
[debug-app-helper] Checking if libmonodroid was unpacked to /data/app/~~EFOmDcU3Iw2KZQfejGsAPg==/com.companyname.rssreadermobile-oa164cL5BGbAG7r5s_Jgnw==/lib/x86_64/libmonodroid.so
[debug-app-helper] Native libs extracted to /data/app/~~EFOmDcU3Iw2KZQfejGsAPg==/com.companyname.rssreadermobile-oa164cL5BGbAG7r5s_Jgnw==/lib/x86_64, assuming application/android:extractNativeLibs == true
[debug-app-helper] Setting up for DSO lookup in app data directories
[debug-app-helper] Added filesystem DSO lookup location: /data/app/~~EFOmDcU3Iw2KZQfejGsAPg==/com.companyname.rssreadermobile-oa164cL5BGbAG7r5s_Jgnw==/lib/x86_64
[debug-app-helper] Using runtime path: /data/app/~~EFOmDcU3Iw2KZQfejGsAPg==/com.companyname.rssreadermobile-oa164cL5BGbAG7r5s_Jgnw==/lib/x86_64
[debug-app-helper] checking directory: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/lib`
[debug-app-helper] directory does not exist: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/lib`
[debug-app-helper] Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/user/0/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[debug-app-helper] Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/app/~~EFOmDcU3Iw2KZQfejGsAPg==/com.companyname.rssreadermobile-oa164cL5BGbAG7r5s_Jgnw==/lib/x86_64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[debug-app-helper] Mono runtime found at: /data/app/~~EFOmDcU3Iw2KZQfejGsAPg==/com.companyname.rssreadermobile-oa164cL5BGbAG7r5s_Jgnw==/lib/x86_64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[rssreadermobil] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[monodroid] Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__`
[rssreadermobil] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=10.0.2.2:63694,embedding=1
[monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46080
[rssreadermobil] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
Loaded assembly: data-0x71cf6225c020 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0x71cf6227c040 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0x71cd07832040 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0x71cf6229c060 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0x71cd4b17c040 [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/netstandard.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointSendToIde(System.String)' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:419 [0x00000].
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/System.Core.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointCheckpoint()' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:414 [0x00000].
[libEGL] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
[libEGL] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
[libEGL] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
[rssreadermobil] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
[rssreadermobil] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'MainPage.xaml.cs:31,1' to void RSSReaderMobile.MainPage.Load (object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e) [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'MainPage.xaml.cs:26,1' to void RSSReaderMobile.MainPage..ctor () [0x00006].
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'MainPage.xaml.g.cs:37,1' to void RSSReaderMobile.MainPage.InitializeComponent () [0x00011].
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/System.Data.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/System.Xml.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/System.Xml.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Thread started:  #3
Thread started:  #4
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.rssreadermobile/files/.__override__/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppLinks.dll
[RecyclerView] Cannot scroll to position a LayoutManager set. Call setLayoutManager with a non-null argument.
[WebViewFactory] Loading com.google.android.webview version 83.0.4103.106 (code 410410686)
[rssreadermobil] The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
[nativeloader] classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/app/WebViewGoogle/lib/x86_64:/product/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk!/lib/x86_64:/product/app/TrichromeLibrary/TrichromeLibrary.apk!/lib/x86_64:/product/lib64:/system/product/lib64
[rssreadermobil] The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
[nativeloader] classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/app/WebViewGoogle/lib/x86_64:/product/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk!/lib/x86_64:/product/app/TrichromeLibrary/TrichromeLibrary.apk!/lib/x86_64:/product/lib64:/system/product/lib64
[cr_VariationsUtils] Requesting new seed from IVariationsSeedServer
[cr_LibraryLoader] Loaded native library version number "83.0.4103.106"
[cr_CachingUmaRecorder] Flushed 3 samples from 3 histograms.
[TetheringManager] registerTetheringEventCallback:com.companyname.rssreadermobile
[chromium] [WARNING:dns_config_service_posix.cc(341)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
Thread started:  #5
[HostConnection] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x71cdf225f950, tid 10676
[HostConnection] HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
[OpenGLRenderer] Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
[EGL_emulation] eglCreateContext: 0x71cde22af4f0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
[EGL_emulation] eglMakeCurrent: 0x71cde22af4f0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x71cd82c179c0) (first time)
[Gralloc4] mapper 4.x is not supported
[HostConnection] createUnique: call
[HostConnection] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x71cdf2260790, tid 10676
[goldfish-address-space] allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
[goldfish-address-space] allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fb047000 size 0x2000
[HostConnection] HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7ffe9b8d5ff8 in tid 10629 (rssreadermobile), pid 10629 (rssreadermobile)
```

Comment: There is a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147793/cannot-start-android-emulator-in-visual-studio-2015-with-xamarin), according to it, there may be some mistake in your code. You can create a new project to test.

Comment: I created a new project and the error still occurred.  I also deleted my emulator and created a new one and the same error happens. I need to find the emulator.exe documentation to understand why that parameter is coming in blank.  It looks like before doing a "SETPROP" it does a "GETPROP." Anyway, I'm still working on it.

Comment: You can try to reinstall the visual studio. Usually, when we install it following the official document, we can run the project on the emulator directly.

Comment: I reinstalled Visual Studio and I'm still getting     setprop "debug.mono.extra" "____"     When adb runs getprop it shows as empty.  I've tried manually running setprop with a valid value and I haven't been able to get it to register.

Comment: Had you checkd [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=windows#deployment-errors)?

Comment: Yes.  I see the emulator as attached.

Comment: Can you show more logs? I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've pasted more logs.  On the Debug log you can see:  [libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7ffe9b8d5ff8.  I'm assuming at this point that this error is caused by the failure in the Xamarin Diagnostic log. I guess it could be I have two separate unrelated errors.

Comment: Hello @LiyunZhang-MSFT, thanks so much for your help on this.  I'm still looking at solutions on my end.  Maybe there's an add-on that's causing the issue?  Would you like to see my XAML?  Hope the logs are helpful.

Comment: The cause shouldn't be that because the problem appeared even though you created a new project.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any updates?
Hangs at "DEBUG RunShellCommand emulator-5554 getprop. (TaskId:13)",